# Detecting the Windows HyperVisor via CLI

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, hyper-v

**How do I detect if the hypervisor is active on Windows via a CLI command?**

I run a vagrant based project that uses VirtualBox, and sometimes we encounter issues with the Windows Hypervisor.

The problem is that the only way we can reliably tell if it's turned on is by asking if Hyper-V is checked in the Windows features dialog. *But there are times when Hyper-V is unchecked, but a hypervisor is present because it's needed for other Windows features*

For example, when using the Windows Susbystem for linux, or when the Virtual Machine platform is turned on, or certain security options.

With VirtualBox 5.2, this was easy, it would fail to create VMs, but with VirtualBox 6, it uses this hypervisor if it's present.

So, either via powershell, or the command line, how can I determine if the Windows hypervisor is present and active?

*Note that I am not testing if the Hyper-V product is active, it is possible for there to be a hypervisor with Hyper-V turned off*

Answer (score 1):

It can be queried via WMI property `Win32_ComputerSystem.HypervisorPresent`. In PowerShell that would be

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).HypervisorPresent
```

Or use `gcim` instead of `Get-WmiObject`.

I tried restarting Windows with `bcdedit /set {current} hypervisorlaunchtype Off` and `Auto`, and it returned `False` and `True` respectively.

What's interesting, property `HypervisorPresent` is hidden from `Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem` output. To see hidden fields, call one of these:

```
gcim Win32_ComputerSystem | Format-List * -Force
gcim Win32_ComputerSystem | Format-Table * -Force
```

Sources:

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-detect-if-hypervisor-is-present/
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-display-hidden-properties-from-object/

Answer (score -1):

Right-click Start > Run > msinfo32

Shown at the bottom of the initial view pane (System Summary) will read the line "A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed."

Comment: But how can I do this in a Vagrant File programmatically? As the question says I need to do this via powershell/command line